# UISplitViewController created programmatically doesn't have swipe gesture to show/hide master

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

I'm struggling in a very strange case: I've created a `UISplitViewController`

```
self.splitViewController = [[UISplitViewController alloc] init];
self.splitViewController.presentsWithGesture = YES;

UIViewController * master = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
master.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
UINavigationController * navMaster = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:master];

UIViewController * detail = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
detail.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
UINavigationController * navDetail = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:detail];

self.splitViewController.viewControllers = @[navMaster,navDetail];

self.window.rootViewController = self.splitViewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

but the swipe gesture (like in Mail app) to open/show master view controller doesn't work in iOS7 but works in iOS8. If I create a new project from Master/Detail template the gesture works. But I need to create `UISplitViewController` programmatically because I have to add after a login page that is a normal view controller. I don't want use storyboard because in this application will be too large.

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing the same problem and found this Awesome Tutorial of how to make it work: [New UISPlitViewController and iOS7](http://whoisryannystrom.com/2014/11/17/UISplitViewController-iOS-7/)

With this you can also use Size Classes and use only 1 Storyboard to support iPhone as well and take advantage of iPhone 6+ landscape Split View functionality.

Note: You have to use Storyboards if you want to use Size Classes and still support iOS 7. (There is no backward compatibility if you use them by code)